# Hi am a new R learner.. wrote below two identical code on editior, 2nd one runs fine, while first one has error.. what is wrong with 1st one

Tags: r

**1st One**

Not run  there is an error

```
repeat{
sc=scan(nmax=1)
if (sc>9) {break} else{
b=switch(sc,"ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE")
cat(“\n The Number Entered is “, sc ,” In Alpha it is  “, b,”\n”) } }
```

the Error is
Error: unexpected input in:
"b=switch(sc,"ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE")
cat(“"

**2nd One**
This one runs ok

```
repeat{
sc=scan(nmax=1)
if (sc>9) {break} else{
b=switch(sc,"ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE")
cat("\n The Entered Number is ", sc ," In Alpha it is ", b,"\n") } }
```

1: 4
Read 1 item
The Entered Number is  4  In Alpha it is  FOUR

Comment: Put the question in the *question body*. Use the title only for what it says - the title.

Comment: They are in no way identical. One uses "special" symbols rather than quotation marks witihn `cat` the other one uses proper quotation marks.

Comment: Greetings ! It would be better if you could provide a little more supporting details about what your problem is and what you are looking for next time.

Answer (score 0):

“ is not allowed in R as a parentheses.

In the first piece of code you are using “ instead of ".

“ may appear if you copy your code into MS Word first and then into .R file.
To securely copy the code pls use Notepad (Notepad++ or IDE) so it preserves " symbol as is and does not transform it into “.

Comment: Thanks for the input, surely will take this as cue for all future works